# Bottom Navigation Bar duplicated

Tags: flutter, dart

I am programming a Bottom Navigation Bar, but the title it's duplicated. The code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _opcaoselecionada = 0;
  final List<Widget> _telas = [
    Menu(),
    HomePage(),
    Graficos(),
  ];

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('bem vindo')
      ),
          body: _telas[_opcaoselecionada],

        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
           currentIndex: _opcaoselecionada,
           onTap: onTabTapped,

          items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              label: "Menu",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.house_outlined),
              label: "inicial",
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.auto_graph),
              label: "graficos",
          )
          ],
         
        ),
      );
    
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _opcaoselecionada = index;
    });
  }
}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Also, everytime I click in the Menu button, it creates a new title. The rest of the code is working properly.

Comment: you are having appBar for all `_telas` children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final List<Widget> _telas = [
    Menu(),
    HomePage(),
    Graficos(),
  ];
```

You need to return only `body part`

remove

```
  appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(label)
      ),
```

from       Menu(),
HomePage(),
Graficos(), this 3 widgets

Comment: It worked, but now when I click in the "inicial" button, it creates a new Bottom Navigation Bar. Do you know how to fix it?